# drag mouse and select in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this react code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [selectedSquare, setSelectedSquare] = useState(null);

  const handleSquareClick = (squareIndex) => {
    setSelectedSquare(squareIndex);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <style>
        {`
        .square-row {
          display: flex;
        }
        
        .square {
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          background-color: #ccc;
          margin-right: 10px;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        .selected {
          background-color: orange;
        }
        `}
      </style>
      <div className="square-row">
        <div
          className={`square ${selectedSquare === 1 ? 'selected' : ''}`}
          onClick={() => handleSquareClick(1)}
        ></div>
        <div
          className={`square ${selectedSquare === 2 ? 'selected' : ''}`}
          onClick={() => handleSquareClick(2)}
        ></div>
        <div
          className={`square ${selectedSquare === 3 ? 'selected' : ''}`}
          onClick={() => handleSquareClick(3)}
        ></div>
      </div>
      <div className="square-row">
        <div
          className={`square ${selectedSquare === 4 ? 'selected' : ''}`}
          onClick={() => handleSquareClick(4)}
        ></div>
        <div
          className={`square ${selectedSquare === 5 ? 'selected' : ''}`}
          onClick={() => handleSquareClick(5)}
        ></div>
        <div
          className={`square ${selectedSquare === 6 ? 'selected' : ''}`}
          onClick={() => handleSquareClick(6)}
        ></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This simulates 6 squares if I click one of them the color changes. I want to know if there's a way I could drag my mouse throughout the area and select multiple of them at the same time, like selecting a bunch of files from the file explorer, but in react.

Answer (score 2):

This is a complex feature to create from scratch, I recommend a library like https://dragselect.com.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it from scratch, you basically need to do the following:

- Listen for the `onMouseMove` event on the `document` and start tracking the mouse coordinates
- Listen for the `onMouseDown` event on the `body` or container element
- When the `onMouseDown` event fires, create a div at the mouse location (position fixed)
- When the `onMouseMove` event fires, change the width/height of the div to create the "selecting" effect. Also, here you check for "collision" with your divs to decide whether or not they should be marked as selected. This on its own can be a bit tricky to implement from scratch.

Alternatively, just use an existing lib like this one https://github.com/unclecheese/react-selectable

Comment: Okay, it sounds tricky and I don't have that much of experience so I will stick with the available libraries. Thank you.